# Error al escribir resultados de regresiones en data frame en R

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr

Estoy realizando una serie de regresiones anuales de corte transversal en R importando datos de un libro de excel en el cual cada hoja corresponde a un año, estos van desde 1995 hasta 2018. Enfrento dos problemas, el primero es que no entiendo cómo puedo agregar al data frame de resultados la lista de coeficientes con sus p-values. El segundo problema es que cuando incorporo los test bp y bg de cada modelo dentro del bucle tira el siguiente error:

```
Error in y - z$residuals : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

El script es el siguiente:

```
library(lmtest)
library(olsrr)
library(tseries)
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx) 
library(dplyr)

años <- 1995:2018 

resultados <- list()

for (año in años) {
  # Define el nombre del archivo Excel (puedes modificarlo según tus necesidades)
  archivo_excel <- "C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Bases/base_Regresiones.xlsx"
  
  # Importa los datos desde la hoja correspondiente al año
  datos <- read_excel(archivo_excel, sheet = as.character(año))

  # Realiza la regresión con tus datos. Por ejemplo, aquí se asume que tienes dos columnas: 'variable_independiente' y 'variable_dependiente'.
  modelo <- lm(y ~ ., data = datos)
  
  # Calcula los estadísticos requeridos
  r_squared <- summary(modelo)$r.squared
  f_statistic <- summary(modelo)$fstatistic[1]
  ssr <- deviance(modelo)
  jb_test <- jarque.bera.test(residuals(modelo))
  bg_test <- bgtest(modelo)
  bp_test <- bptest(modelo)
  
  # Almacena los resultados en la lista, incluyendo el R-squared y el estadístico F
  resultados[[as.character(año)]] <- list(
    Año = año,
    R_squared = r_squared,
    F_statistic = f_statistic,
    u_squad = ssr,
    JBtest = jb_test$p.value,
    bgtest = bg_test$p.value,
    bptest = bp_test$p.value
  )
}

# Crear un DataFrame a partir de la lista de resultados
resultados_df <- do.call(rbind, resultados)
```

Espero obtener algo como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error lo que seguramente está diciendo, es que `y`  es un valor no numérico. Por otro lado, dale una mirada al paquete `broom` : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html

Comment: El error proviene de las hojas de excel. Tenía texto en las últimas filas